# Why does the fork() function return the PID of the main process with a value that is 1 greater?

Tags: c, process, pid

I tried to write my "getpid" clone because i have a school project and getpid is forbidden function. So, i wrote this code:

```c
pid_t   mini_getpid(void)
{
    pid_t   id;

    id = fork();
    if (id == 0)
        exit(0);
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        return (id - 1);
    }
}
```

I tried to get main process's pid with using fork function. But there is a problem. When i compare my return and real getpid() function, my function always return 1 greater. For example, if getpid()'s return is 1000 then my function gives me 1001 because of fork function. What is the fork function doing wrong and why does it return the PID value as one greater than it should be?

Comment: `What is the fork function doing wrong` its not doing anything wrong. `why does it return the PID value as one greater than it should be?` it returns exactly what its supposed to return, the children's PID.

Comment: The child pid returned to the parent process has nothing to do with the parents pid (aside from it **not** being the parent's, of course). Returning that pid minus 1 is... weird and not right.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  If you're not allowed to use `getpid`, why do you think you need the pid?

Answer (score 0):

Fork [returns the *child's* PID](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), and it's pure luck that it's been consistently 1 higher than the parent on your machine and environment, so far. That's not a guarantee; the kernel can assign any valid, unused PID for the child.

If you really need to getpid without calling the getpid C function, you could always [call the raw syscall](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sys.c#n958):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
int main(void) {
  pid_t pid = syscall(SYS_getpid);
  pid_t pid2 = getpid(); // for comparison
  printf("%d %d\n", pid, pid2);
  return 0;
}
```

If the spirit of your task is to not even use that syscall, you'll have to explore other side channels that provide the info you need. The best approach would obviously depend on what things you are and aren't allowed to do in your assignment.

One other possible (but inefficient) approach would be to have some kind of communication channel from the child process to the parent (e.g. shared memory, pipe, etc) and a `getppid` call in the child.

Comment: On Linux, you could do `readlink("/proc/self", buffer, sizeof(buffer));`.  Other unixy systems might support something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You are making assumptions about the relation between the parent pid and the child pid that shouldn't be made. The child pid could be anything, so `child_pid - 1` is *not* the correct way to get the parent pid.

If `getpid()` is the only forbidden function, you could use `getppid()` (to get the parent pid) in the child process and then send that back to the parent via a `pipe`.

Here's an example. Adding error checking is left as an exercise.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { P_RD, P_WR };

pid_t mini_getpid(void) {
    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);                             // create a pipe

    pid_t id = fork();
    if (id == 0) {
        close(fds[P_RD]);                  // close the reading end of the pipe
        pid_t parent = getppid();          // get parent pid
        write(fds[P_WR], &parent, sizeof parent); // send pid to parent
        close(fds[P_WR]);                  // close the writing end
        exit(0);
    }
    // in parent process
    int mypid;
    close(fds[P_WR]);                      // close the writing end       
    read(fds[P_RD], &mypid, sizeof mypid); // read the pid from the pipe
    close(fds[P_RD]);                      // close the reading end
    
    int wstatus;
    waitpid(id, &wstatus, 0);              // wait for child to exit

    return mypid;
}
```